# Can I use MinGW compiled Python extensions together with Visual C++ compiled ones?

Tags: python, windows, compilation, python-extensions

Having trouble compiling a Python extension under Windows, I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709641/cant-compile-msgpack-python-extension-under-windows).One of the answers does not answer my question but is worth asking as a question on its own.

Given a Visual C++ compiled Python distribution under Windows, would I have any problems if I use Visual C++ compiled extensions along with MinGW compiled ones?

This would allow me resort to MinGW when it is easier than configuring MS compiler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not officially supported, but I think it should work. Python exposes `extern "C"` functions (with C linkage), so you should be able to call them from MSVC. But that's only Python itself. What about extensions? `PyMODINIT_FUNC` also has `extern "C"` in it, so that allows to call it from MSVC, too. Functions that you pass to Python by function pointer should  also work, because they use `cdecl` calling convention by default, but do not need C linkage (or C name mangling) because they are called by pointer. To sum up, it should Just Work™.